# Using a regex pattern gives compile error "Invalid regular expression"

Tags: regex, typescript, compiler-errors, angular6

I'm trying to use the regex from https://www.regextester.com/94502
inside my angular app.

So i copied the regex and placed it between two / characters...

```
websiteRegex = /?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'^(?:http(s)\(\)\*\+,;=.]+$/;

website: ['', [Validators.maxLength(250), Validators.pattern(this.websiteRegex)]]
```

But this leads to compile error:

```
Module parse failed: Invalid regular expression: /?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'^(?:http(s)\(\)\*\+,;=.]+$/: Nothing to repeat
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: You lost the first `^(`. However, the regex is probably not what you need since you have `^(?:http(s)` inside the last character class.

Comment: I just noticed that something went wrong when copying the regex to my angular code

Answer (score 0):

Works fine when using the correct regex...

```
websiteRegex = /^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+$/;
```